# minecraft liquid logistic pipes, which ones i need

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I am using ftb unleashed 1.1.3 and trying to use logistic pipes to get from an ender tank to geothermal generator, and can not figure out what pipe goes on the tank, what goes in between and what goes on geothermal generator.

So my question is; what pipe goes on the tank, what goes in between and what goes on geothermal generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a Liquid Extractor Pipe on Tank, and Basic Liquid Pipes on Geothermal Generator and regular Build Craft pipes in between.
To See More Watch this Video at this Certain Time:

Comment: i didnt power the pipes. that was the problem lol. thnx